# Fried Spaghetti

Tags: frying, pasta, boiling, noodles

Pasta, as far as I'm aware, is always boiled to serve. However, their eastern cousin, noodles, are often fried. Are there any well-known Western (Italian) dishes that use fried fresh pasta, instead of boiling it?

If not, why do you think that's the case? Does pasta not fry well?

Comment: I have a stir-fried fusilli recipe, but it's not traditional, just a chef rebooting classic carbonara.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We used to have fried spaghetti for leftovers growing up. Take cooked spaghetti in sauce and put it in a warm frying pan with a little oil.

I've also had noodle fritters with leftover spaghetti, take undressed spaghetti and dip in a batter, then pan or deep fry. Somewhat like a potato pancake, we would eat them with sour cream.

Answer (score 2):

Would you count [Toasted Ravioli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toasted_ravioli) - breaded and deep fried (and delicious!)?

Comment: I guess I would, although I've never heard of this and the Wikipedia page implies it's a modern invention... I wonder if there's any traditional fried pasta dishes?

Comment: Deep-frying itself is relatively modern (a few hundred years among the wealthy, and only since the industrial age among non-elites), due to the historically high cost of extracting large quantities of oil. What do you consider "traditional"?

Answer (score 1):

When making *pasta e fagioli* my grandmother (from Lecce, in Apulia) would fry some of the pasta and cook most of it with the bean soup: then she would add the fried pasta to the boiling pot at the last moment, so that it would retain some of its crunchiness. It is a good trick, guests are always very surprised by the variation in texture.